# Reputation entry not showing in the Reputation Tab

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, caching

I gained 20 reputation on two events but why am I not able to see it in the Reputation Tab?

> [image]

Is it some fault or feature of SO?  Note: I have refreshed my page thrice but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: The reputation tab is cached, probably for couple of minutes, while the reputation in the hovering "card" is live, or at least cached for less time.

Comment: [It seems to be ok,](http://i.imgur.com/Bs3B9.png) show a little patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes sometime to update the Reputation tab. Probably your Reputations are update first and then Reputation Tab. Many a times I too see that happening. My reputations are increased/decreased but the Reputation Tab is still not updated.

Comment: hmm, this may be the cause.

Answer (score 3):

No repro:

> [image]

Wait longer?  Clear your cache?

Comment: already waited about 30sec and refresh, but nothing happened

Comment: @hotveryspicy, it's general, common **cache** problem on each SE site, nothing else.